# Can/cannot one integrate over a measurable set $A \subset [-\pi, \pi]$?

Tags: measure-theory, definite-integrals

So this has caused some confusion. In one exercise one was asked to prove that

$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int_A \cos(kt)dt=0$$

where $A \subset [-\pi, \pi]$ is a measurable set.

My initial idea was to take any $a,b \in A$ and then show that:

$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int_a^b cos(kt)dt= \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sin(bk)-\sin(ak)}{k} =0$$

But my instructor said that this wouldn't work out because the lengths of the partitions on $A$ would make my computation impossible. I'm not sure about this.

Comment: It seems that you're assuming that $[a,b]\subset A$.  It is not clear that this is true (and there might be no intervals in $A$).

Comment: @MichaelBurr Why can't one take any two elements in $A$? And why would a measurable set on a real line not have intervals?

Comment: You can take two elements of $A$ (assuming axiom of choice, perhaps), but why are all the elements between $a$ and $b$ within $A$?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Because it's measurable?

Comment: Measurable does not imply that it is connected.

Comment: What if $A=[-\pi,\pi]\setminus\mathbb{Q}$?  This set contains no intervals, so the integral you compute might not be related to $A$ (in this case, $\mathbb{Q}$ is measure zero, so you can say something).

Comment: Your approach can be made to work. First show the result is true for an interval, and hence finite collections of disjoint intervals. Then DCT shows that it is true if $A$ is a countable collections of disjoint intervals. Hence it is true for open $A$. Finally use regularity of the Lebesgue measure to conclude.

Comment: You don't need the axiom of choice here!

Answer (score 3):

Trying to use an interval as a replacement for $A$ is not a good approach. $A$ could be a very complicated set, after all; it could be a countable union of intervals, or a set like the irrationals, or some totally disconnected Cantor set with positive measure. There is a general principle that measurable sets are *like* countable unions of intervals for many purposes, but this approach goes too far.

So there is *very* little relationship between the interval $[a, b]$ and the set $A$, even with $a, b \in A$.

---

For an approach that you might find more successful: The integral you've written is the real part of the $k$-th Fourier coefficient of $\chi_A$ (the indicator function of $A$). What does Plancherel tell you?

Comment: I was told to use Bessel inequality.

Comment: And Bessel's inequality is pretty close to Plancherel, FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f=1_A$, and note that $f \in L^2[-\pi,\pi]$.

Let $\hat{f}_n = {1 \over 2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t) e^{-int} dt$.

Bessel's inequality gives
$\sum_n |\hat{f}_n|^2 \le \|f\|_2^2$, and so $\hat{f}_n \to 0$.

Another approach would be the Riemann Lebesgue lemma.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your approach is a good start, but you have to extend your result to general measurable sets. You can do that by approximation.

Let $\mathbb T=[-\pi, \pi)$.

**Step 1**. Show that for any open set $O\subset \mathbb T$, it holds that $\lim_{k\to \infty} \int_O \cos(kt)\, dt =0$. To do this, use the fact that every open set in $\mathbb T$ is a countable disjoint union of intervals. Since $\mathbb T$ has a finite total measure, most of $O$ must be concentrated on a finite disjoint union of intervals. More precisely, for all $N\in\mathbb N$, $O$ can be decomposed as  $$O=\bigcup_{j=1}^N (a_j, b_j) + R_N,\ \text{where }|R_N|\le\tfrac 1 N.$$
Now use the computation you have already done.

**Step 2**. Fix $\epsilon>0$. We know from measure theory that every measurable set $M\subset \mathbb T$ is contained in an open set $O_\epsilon$ in such a way that $|O_\epsilon \setminus M|\le \epsilon$. (Absolute value of a set denotes Lebesgue measure). So 
$$
\left| \int_M \cos(kt)\, dt\right|\le \left| \int_{O\setminus M} \cos(kt)\, dt \right| + \left| \int_O \cos(kt)\, dt\right| \le \epsilon + \eta_k, $$ 
where $\eta_k\to 0$ as $k\to \infty$.